# Is it possible to generate example table for scenario in specflow?

Tags: bdd, specflow

The main problem is that example table is too long (below the example is a mock short, my real test would be ~300 lines). Is it possible to generate these table? I have mypage30.. it would be hard to maintain it

```
Scenario Outline: Check categories
Given I visit '<mypage>'
When I select '<category>'
Then the selected category is shown

Examples: 
| mypage | category |
| page1  | mouse    |
| page1  | cat      |
| page1  | horse    |
| page1  | do       |
| page1  | duck     |
| page2  | mouse    |
| page2  | cat      |
| page2  | horse    |
| page2  | do       |
| page2  | duck     |
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's impossible to generate a content of .feature file automatically**.

Yet I guess in your case you can make it other way.

**One way is to store your table in .xlsx file** and to use this file as a data source.

If you choose this option, it's very simply implemented in SpecFlow: https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/Prepare-feature-files-for-external-examples/
All you need is to specify the path to your source file:

```
@source:CalculatorExamples.xlsx
Examples:
    | case | a | b | result |
```

Another way is to generate all the data within your test scenario. I don't know how you wanted to generate this table so I assume that the first way is better.

Comment: the xlsx file solution is only available for specflow+

Can you write an example for the other way, when generate data in test scenario

Comment: @TiborKovács load file in a step definition and use it as a source. It will be a little bit harder as you need to parse it by yourself.